How do I show this thumbnail on Pillow?
I am learning to use Pillow. I am trying to display the thumbnail but don't know how.
Here is my current code:
img = Image.open('block.jpg')
new = img.thumbnail((400,400),Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

I've tried using
img.resize((400,400),Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

but since I'm using a 16*16 pixel image, the quality drops a lot.
When I try new.show() I get an error.

thumbnail doesn't return a new image like most functions do, it modifies the image in-place.  So setting new to the return value ends up with it being None which doesn't have a show() method.
If you're starting with a 16x16 image and trying to blow it up to 400x400, it's going to look bad no matter what method you use.
